# Topic modeling for short length sentences

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, clustering, text-mining, lda

I have a graph which was already separated into clusters. Each node in the graph has a label (typically, it's a function's name like `org.java.somepackage.validateLogin`). What I want to do is to give a **representative label** for each cluster.

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume I'm able to clean the data (i.e. break 'validateLogin' to 'validate' and 'login')

I've done a little research on the subjects of *topics modeling* and *cluster labeling* and encountered a few algorithms, such as: LDA, NMF and TF-IDF (not quite an algorithm on itself)

Basically, many algorithms are documents oriented which are reach of words and not short-text/labels oriented.

It is worth mentioning:

- We can use the fact that different clusters might have different labels, so maybe a proper label for a cluster could be unique words in the overall bag of words (that can be done with TF-IDF I guess)
- Labels can be one word but can also imply a hierarchy (i.e. `packageA.packageB.packageC.funcName`)

I'd be glad if you could give me your insights on this problem and what approach could fit here.

Comment: I think you have it correct. As you mentioned in your post, TF-IDF is document based. I think you can get the word frequency and then Name each cluster with the most frequent word. If you want hierarchical clusters, you can take each main clusters and do a topic modeling or k-means clustering and take the word(term) frequencies again and take the top name for sub cluster name.

Comment: Do these Java packages have any documentation? You could use the descriptions of the packages from the documentation as input for those algorithms that you found.

Comment: @SergiyKolesnikov, Unfortunately, that is the only extracted data.

Comment: Notice that Java packages have particular semantics. A cluster, represented by *org* bears very different semantics than a cluster, represented by *validate*, *util* or *service*. Thus your data is very different from natural text. If you fail to use this information, it might distort your results.

Answer (score 2):

A possible approach might be to use the most predictable and predictive word(s) in each cluster as its name(s). The following is inspired by Fisher's [category utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_utility) used by the [COBWEB algorithm](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1022852608280).

An attribute is highly **predictable** in a cluster $C_l$ if most elements in that cluster have the same value $a$ for it, thus a word represented by attribute $A_i$ has a predictability of $P(A_i=a|C_l)$

An attribute is highly **predictive** for a cluster $C_l$ if knowing it's value $a$ implies you can say with high certainty to which cluster it belongs, expressed as $P(C_l|A_i=a)$

Assume now you process each label `org.java.somepackage.validateLogin` as a sentence: *"org java somepackage validate Login"* and apply [one-hot encoding](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#encoding-categorical-features) to all your sentences in the dataset. The occurrence of a word is now represented by a value of 1 for it's corresponding attribute.

The task of representing each cluster by a word can now be formulated as finding for each cluster $C_l$ the word represented by attribute $A_i$ that equals 1 and has the highest predictability and predictiveness, weighted by the total probability of this word being in a sentence.

$$ P(A_i=1|C_l)\times P(C_l|A_i=1) \times P(A_i=1)$$

Which can be calculated by counting occurrence of a word per cluster and cluster per word.

Answer (score 1):

Your research has yielded results like LDA, NMF, etc. But since you want to keep your concentration to short texts and generate short labels, I would recommend you to check this algorithm called: **Bi Term Topic Model for Short Texts.**

Here is the paper from the author: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.402.4032&rep=rep1&type=pdf

And here is the code from the author again: https://github.com/xiaohuiyan/BTM

I have used this personally and can very vouch for this for its performance.